# Using "either" in this sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, conjunctions

I wrote:

> Multiple conditions of either ContextMatching or NodeMatching type can be combined using logical operators (and, or) to form a single condition for each rule.

I want to say both types are possible to be combined in a rule. Does it mean what I expect? because I thought "either" could be exclusive.

Answer (score 1):

Either can be exclusive - you need to say *or both* to be certain that it will have the meaning you intend.

For instance:

> Multiple conditions of either ContextMatching or NodeMatching type **or both** can be combined using logical operators (and, or) to form a single condition for each rule.